# Option type benchmark using F#

Tags: f#, null, option-type, benchmarking

I need to use Some/None options in heavy numerical simulations. The following micro benchmark gives me `Fast = 485` and `Slow = 5890`.

I do not like nulls and even if I liked them I cannot use null because `The type 'float' does not have 'null' as a proper value`.

Ideally there would be a compiler option that would compile Some/None into value/null so there would be no runtime penalty. Is that possible? Or how shall I make Some/None efficient?

```
let s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()

s.Start()
for h in 0 .. 1000 do
  Array.init 100000 (fun i -> (float i + 1.)) |> ignore
printfn "Fast = %d" s.ElapsedMilliseconds

s.Restart()
for h in 0 .. 1000 do
  Array.init 100000 (fun i -> Some (float i + 1.)) |> ignore
printfn "Slow = %d" s.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`None` is actually already represented as `null`.  But since `option<_>` is a reference type (which is necessary for `null` to be a valid value in the .NET type system), creating `Some` instances will necessarily require heap allocations.  One alternative is to use the .NET `System.Nullable<_>` type, which is similar to `option<_>`, except that:

1. it's a value type, so no heap allocation is needed
2. it only supports value types as elements, so you can create an `option<string>`, but not a `Nullable<string>`.  For your use case this seems like an unimportant factor.
3. it has runtime support so that boxing a nullable without a value results in a null reference, which would be impossible otherwise

Keep in mind that your benchmark does very little work, so the results are probably not typical of what you'd see with your real workload.  Try to use a more meaningful benchmark based on your actual scenario if at all possible.

As a side note, you get more meaningful diagnostics (including garbage collection statistics) if you use the `#time` directive in F# rather than bothering with the `Stopwatch`.

Comment: really? I didn't know `#time` is better than `Stopwatch`.

Comment: That sounds good. How exactly shall I use Nullable e.g. in pattern matching?

Comment: @OldrichSvec - well, there are only two cases, so I'd probably just use an `if nbl.HasValue then ... nbl.Value ... else ...`, but you could also define a `(|NullableSome|NullableNone|)` active pattern if you prefer to use pattern matching.